# How to close a floating window from a recyclerview adapter

Tags: java, android-recyclerview

I have created an app where a floating window pops up into the screen when a specific time reaches. The floating window contains a recycler view that displays a list of items. I have placed a method that dismisses the floating window when an item in the recycler view is clicked but it's not been triggered. How do I solve this issue?

This is the Window class.

```
public class Window {

// declaring required variables
private Context context;
private View mView;
private TheFloatingWindowAppsAdapter theFloatingWindowAppsAdapter;
private WindowManager.LayoutParams mParams;
private WindowManager mWindowManager;
private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;

public Window(Context context) {
    this.context = context;

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        // set the layout parameters of the window
        mParams = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
                // Shrink the window to wrap the content rather
                // than filling the screen
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                // Display it on top of other application windows
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_APPLICATION_OVERLAY,
                // Don't let it grab the input focus
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE,
                // Make the underlying application window visible
                // through any transparent parts
                PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
    }

    // getting a LayoutInflater
    layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    // inflating the view with the custom layout we created
    mView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.theheartlayout, null);

    mView.setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY
    );

    String thepassingDate = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd, yyyy", Locale.getDefault()).format(new Date());

    TextClock time = mView.findViewById(R.id.hourText);
    TextView theDateText = mView.findViewById(R.id.theDateText);
    RecyclerView upnext_tasksID = mView.findViewById(R.id.upnext_tasksID);
    RecyclerView app_listID = mView.findViewById(R.id.app_listID);
    List<AppDetails> appDetailsList = new ArrayList<>();
    TheFloatingWindowAppsAdapter theFloatingWindowAppsAdapter = new TheFloatingWindowAppsAdapter(appDetailsList, context);
    app_listID.setHasFixedSize(true);
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(context, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
    app_listID.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

    app_listID.setAdapter(theFloatingWindowAppsAdapter);
    theDateText.setText(thepassingDate);

    displayItems(appDetailsList, theFloatingWindowAppsAdapter);

    // Define the position of the
    // window within the screen
    mParams.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;
    mWindowManager = (WindowManager) context.getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);

}

public void open() {
    try {
        // check if the view is already
        // inflated or present in the window
        if (mView.getWindowToken() == null) {
            if (mView.getParent() == null) {
                mWindowManager.addView(mView, mParams);
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d("Error1", e.toString());
    }

}

public void close() {
    try {
        // remove the view from the window
        ((WindowManager) context.getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE)).removeView(mView);
        // invalidate the view
        mView.invalidate();
        // remove all views
        ((ViewGroup) mView.getParent()).removeAllViews();

        // the above steps are necessary when you are adding and removing
        // the view simultaneously, it might give some exceptions
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d("Error2", e.toString());
    }
}

private void displayItems(List<AppDetails> appDetailsList, TheFloatingWindowAppsAdapter adapter) {
    FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    FirebaseUser firebaseUser = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();

    DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Selected Apps")
            .child(firebaseUser.getUid());
    reference.keepSynced(true);

    reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
            appDetailsList.clear();
            for (DataSnapshot sn : snapshot.getChildren()) {
                AppDetails appDetails = sn.getValue(AppDetails.class);

                if (appDetails.getAppid() != null) {
                    appDetailsList.add(appDetails);
                }

            }

            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

        }
    });

}
}
```

This is the Recyclerview Adapter

```
public class TheFloatingWindowAppsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<TheFloatingWindowAppsAdapter.ViewHolder> {

List<AppDetails> appDetailsList;
Context context;
View view;

public TheFloatingWindowAppsAdapter(List<AppDetails> appDetailsList, Context context) {
    this.appDetailsList = appDetailsList;
    this.context = context;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.thefloatingwindowapps, parent, false);
    return new ViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    AppDetails appDetails = appDetailsList.get(position);
    holder.displayedName.setText(appDetails.getAppname());


    holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(view -> {
        Intent intent = context.getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage(appDetails.getPackagename());

        if (intent != null) {
            context.startActivity(intent);
            Window window = new Window(context);
            window.close();
        }
    });

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return appDetailsList.size();
}

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    TextView displayedName;
    private Window window = new Window(context);

    public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        displayedName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.displayedName);
    }

}
}
```

This is the Foreground Class

```
public class ForegroundServices extends Service {
public ForegroundServices() {

}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not yet implemented");
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    // create the custom or default notification
    // based on the android version
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
        startMyOwnForeground();
    else
        startForeground(1, new Notification());

    // create an instance of Window class
    // and display the content on screen
    Window window = new Window(this);
    window.open();
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
}

// for android version >=O we need to create
// custom notification stating
// foreground service is running
@RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
private void startMyOwnForeground() {
    String NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID = "example.permanence";
    String channelName = "Background Service";
    NotificationChannel chan = new NotificationChannel(NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID, channelName, NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_MIN);

    NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    assert manager != null;
    manager.createNotificationChannel(chan);

    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID);
    Notification notification = notificationBuilder.setOngoing(true)
            .setContentTitle("Service running")
            .setContentText("Displaying over other apps")

            // this is important, otherwise the notification will show the way
            // you want i.e. it will show some default notification
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher_foreground)

            .setPriority(NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_MIN)
            .setCategory(Notification.CATEGORY_SERVICE)
            .build();
    startForeground(2, notification);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've found a solution after four days of struggling.

First initialize your Window class inside the RecyclerView Adapter.

```
Window window;
```

Then add the Window class in your constructor inside your recycler view adapter.

```
 public RecyclerViewAdapter(Window window){
        this.window = window;
     }
```

Inside your Window class initalize your adapter

```
 RecyclerViewAdapter recyclerviewAdapter = new RecyclerviewAdapter(this);
```